# android how to using sweet-alert-dialog on Eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse, import

When I trying to use this library :
https://github.com/pedant/sweet-alert-dialog

using(Eclipse) in my application I got an error :
(ProgressWheel cannot be resolved to a type)

can any one help me to make this library work in my (eclipse) workspace ?!

thanks in advance

Comment: Hey I downloaded the library, extracted, but when when I am importing in eclipse, the src folder is empty and errors. Please help.. How can I import it in eclipse

Comment: Hi, I have tried downloading and compiling but can seem to make it work. Also tried suggested solution here. Do you maybe have a compiled version I can download - it would really help me. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sweet-alert has a dependency which the library failed to mention at their page.

> https://github.com/pnikosis/materialish-progress

after setting up the progress bar library reference it to the sweet-alert library and it will work fine.

Don't forget the steps required to import a gradle project to eclipse